# Tensor products and intersections in non-commutative setting

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra, flatness

Let $N,M$ be submodules of a right module $P$ over a non-commutative ring $R$. let $Q$ be a left flat $R$ module. Then is it true that

$(N \cap M) \otimes_R Q \cong (N \cap Q) \otimes_R (M \cap Q)?$

Can anyone give me a reference? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112594

Comment: See proposition 1.6 (1) here: http://www2.gsu.edu/~matfxe/commalglectures/lect18.pdf